# OCR of pdf file using google cloud API

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-platform

I want to OCR pdf using google API, but in the following syntax I get 400 errors. What should I do now

```
        str_json_data = {
        "requests": [
            {
                "inputConfig": {
                    "content" : "20001008.pdf",
                    "mimeType" : "application/pdf"
                },
                "features": [
                    {
                        "type" : "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    obj_session = Session()
    obj_request = Request("POST",
                          str_url + str_api_key,
                          data=json.dumps(str_json_data),
                          headers=str_headers
                          )
    obj_prepped = obj_session.prepare_request(obj_request)
    obj_response = obj_session.send(obj_prepped,
                                    verify=True,
                                    timeout=60
                                    )
```

google cloud strage I want to know how to not use it

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are using this API call: `vision.files.asyncBatchAnnotate` using the library `Cloud Vision API v1`. I'm not able to find the parameter `requests -> inputConfig -> content` take a look at this:

[image: inputConfig]

Please, try to set the parameters as specified [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf#vision-pdf-detection-gcs-protocol) and run again your request, it worked well for me.